# SVG image as background in CSS

Tags: css

I am using the following code to achieve a fullscreen background in css, which seems to be working fine.

```
    html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but i have a major issue, the client asked me to show a part of the logo in bigger size in the background and once we scale it should not get pixelated. so i assumed that the logo has to be in svg format but dont know how to merge with the background.

can anyone help please.

Comment: What do you mean by merge with the background? Do you have a JSFiddle example of your problem?

Comment: yes you can. multiple backgrounds are possible. however, before using svg please cross check with: http://caniuse.com/svg-css

Comment: Use multiple backgrounds http://jsfiddle.net/D4GjP/